# How to convert date format in c#?

Tags: c#

I am getting data from XML in format of MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt (e.g 7/21/2016 5:43:03 PM) but I want to convert it into date format of only dd/MM/yyyy (e.g 21/7/2016)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                 .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Initially, using the `ParseExact` you create a `DateTime` object based on your input and later using the `ToString` you create the string representation of your `DateTime` in the specified format.

For info about the `DateTime.ParseExact` have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: my xml date is '6/30/2016 11:45:32 AM ' and my code to convert is DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") but still i am getting error {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a quick trick:

```
string date = "7/21/2016 5:43:03 PM";

var dateOnly = DateTime.Parse(date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Explanation:

```
DateTime.Parse(date)    <--- Converts the string to DateTime object.
ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")  <--- Converts the DateTime Object to the specified format.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = "7/21/2016 5:43:03 PM";//Date from XML
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out dateTime))
{
    var dateOnly = dateTime.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy");
}
```